# Uncaught Error: Minified React error #306 ，Mac OS Firefox browser

Tags: reactjs

react 16.14.0
On my Mac. Firefox reported an error. I searched for a long time and couldn't find a solution. I tried to change the route in the project, but it still hasn't been solved,Chrome and edge are normal, and Firefox version is 100.0.1 (the latest version)

https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?args=undefined&args=&invariant=306

[image: error img]

Comment: Never seen this error before. So is this working on other browsers? Safari and Chrome? It does you have said... Interesting...